# How do I update Reactjs State with data I retrieved using a fetch API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, state, prop

I made a fetch API call in react.js and put it inside a variable defined within the function containing the fetch function. But how do I transfer this value to one of the variables in the state? I can get to the point where I console.log the variable, but still I'm not able to figure out how to update one of the state variables so that I can then display the retrieved data onto the page.

```
import React from 'react';

class Stock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stockInfo: '100'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchStock();
  }

  fetchStock() {
    const API_KEY = 'api key goes here';
    let TimeInterval = '60min';
    let StockSymbol = 'AMZN';
    let API_Call = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=${StockSymbol}&interval=${TimeInterval}&outputsize=compact&apikey=${API_KEY}`;
    let stockHistoryDatabase = {};
    let stockHistoryDatabaseString;

    fetch(API_Call)
      .then(
        function(response) {
          return response.json();
        }
      )
      .then(
        function(data) {
          console.log(data);

          for (var key in data['Time Series (60min)']) {
            // push the key value pair of the time stamp key and the opening value key paired together into an object with a key value pair data set storage.
            var epochKeyTime = new Date(key);
            epochKeyTime = epochKeyTime.getTime();
            stockHistoryDatabase[epochKeyTime] = data['Time Series (60min)'][key]['1. open'];
          }

          console.log(stockHistoryDatabase);
          stockHistoryDatabaseString = JSON.stringify(stockHistoryDatabase);
          console.log(stockHistoryDatabaseString);
        }
      );
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      stockInfo: 'hello'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Stocks</h1>
        <p>{this.state.stockInfo}</p>
        <button onClick={this.handleChange}>Change</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Stock;
```

this is my code in entirety. I know how to change the state using a separate function that is called from a button click on the same page, but I'm unable to get the data stored in the variable 'stockHistoryDatabaseString' to replace the state 'stockInfo'.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: if I use the 'this.setState' method in the fetch api call area, the 'this' portion can't refer to the correct place, perhaps I can change that to refer to the state somehow properly?

Comment: You should be able to use `this.setState` in second `then` method. Use arrow function in `.then` so that it point to correct context

Comment: before fetch use _this=this and use _this.setState @SimonSuh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. My solution to this problem was to store `this` context of react class into one variable and then use it in any scope below it.

```
fetchStock() {
 const pointerToThis = this; // points to context of current react class
 fetch(API_Call)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(pointerToThis); // you can use pointerToThis which in turn points to react class 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling `fetchStock` after component is mounting. You can use arrow function as follows.

```
.then((data) => {
   // use data here
   this.setState({ ... }) // set you state
})
```

or if you are not comfortable using arrow function, then I believe you can create a function to handle the promise e.g. `handleData`

```
.then(this.handleData)
```

in class

```
// pseudo code

class YourClass extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchStock()
  }
  handleData = (data) => {
    // process your data and set state
  }
  fetchStock() {
    // your API call
    fetch(API_CALL).then(this.handleData);
  }
  render() {}
}
```

If you are invoking `fetchStock` on user operation, such as button click, then you can provide appropriate context to `fetchStock` by binding it to React class you've created as follows:

```
constructor() {
  this.fetchStock = this.fetchStock.bind(this);
}
```

or there is another way to achieve the same (perhaps cleaner way):

```
fetchStock = () => {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First inside constructor add

```
this.fetchStock = this.fetchStock.bind(this);
```

Update fetchStock function like this:

```
fetchStock() {
  const API_KEY = 'api key goes here';
  let TimeInterval = '60min';
  let StockSymbol = 'AMZN';
  let API_Call = `https://www.alphavantage.co/queryfunction=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=${StockSymbol}&interval=${TimeInterval}&outputsize=compact&apikey=${API_KEY}`;

  let stockHistoryDatabase = {};
  let stockHistoryDatabaseString;

  fetch(API_Call)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      for (var key in data['Time Series (60min)']) {
        var epochKeyTime = new Date(key);
        epochKeyTime = epochKeyTime.getTime();
        stockHistoryDatabase[epochKeyTime] = data['Time Series (60min)'][key]['1. open'];
      }
    this.setState({stockInfo: stockHistoryDatabase}) 
    //Set your state here.

    stockHistoryDatabaseString = JSON.stringify(stockHistoryDatabase);
  }
  );
```

}